# How to rewrite request specs without `page` and `visit` methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

Before the latest changes to capybara and rspec, request specs were allowed to use the `page` and `visit` methods. Integration tests worked well allowing you to test across the model, view and controller. So testing something like following and unfollowing users was simple

```
describe "User" do

  context "Relationships" do

    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }
    let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }

    before do
      sign_in user
    end

    describe "Following a user" do

    before do
      visit user_path(other_user)
    end

      it "will increment the followed user count" do
        expect do
          click_button "Follow"
        end.to change(user.followeds, :count).by(1)
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Now this is the request spec rewritten as a feature spec as recommended by capybara and rspec

```
feature "Relationships" do

  given!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }
  given!(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }

  background do
    sign_in user
  end

  scenario "following another user" do
    visit user_path(other_user)
    click_button "Follow"
    expect(page).to have_button "Unfollow"
  end
end
```

It seems its more difficult or impossible to get the same detail in a feature spec as compared to requests specs with the `page` and `visit` methods.

Can anyone show how to rewrite the request spec to test the same things with only the `response` object and without `page` and `visit`?

And also I know about including them back into request specs but its not recommended.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know that these methods are only available for feature specs by default, but why are you rewriting the tests? When we upgraded, we just moved our `request` directory to `features`.

Comment: I know what your saying but feature specs are suppose to use feature and scenario rather than describe and it. I'm just asking if someone knows how to do the same tests in the request spec without using `page` and `visit`

Comment: feature specs can be nested - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/1113

Comment: @AndreyBotalov ah thanks for the heads up. I didn't know this changed. It was difficult to test certain situations without nesting. This is helpful